# Unable to download artifact from Nexus which does not have type

Tags: gradle, nexus

I need to download a file from Nexus through Gradle but the file 'ext' is null. Here is my build.gradle file:

```
configurations {
  iewin64driver
  chromelinuxdriver}

dependencies {
  iewin64driver "com.seleniumdrivers:ie-driver:latest.release:win64@exe"
  chromelinuxdriver "com.seleniumdrivers:chrome-driver:latest.release:linux"
  }

 //Download selenium drivers from Nexus to libs directory and rename
  task downloadDrivers(type: Copy) {

  //IEDriver Win64
  from configurations.iewin64driver
  into file("/libs")
  rename  '(.*)win64(.*)', "iedriver.exe"


  //ChromeDriver Linux
  from configurations.chromelinuxdriver
  into file("/libs")  
  rename  'chrome-driver(.*)linux', "chromedriver-linux"
  println "completed download drivers"
```

}

While the ieWindriver64 which refers to filename "ie-driver-3.9.0-win32.exe" downloads without any issues, the second one chromelinuxdriver does not download because the filename to be downloaded is "chrome-driver-2.37-linux"
Note this file does not have any extension.

By default gradle looks for .jar if extension is not provided and returns error message:
   "Could not find chrome-driver-linux.jar"

I also tried different options like but doesn't work:

```
dependencies {
chromelinuxdriver group: "com.seleniumdrivers", name: "chrome-driver", 
version: "2.37", classifier: "linux", ext: null }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be possible. [This plugin](https://github.com/energizedwork/webdriver-binaries-gradle-plugin), which helps incorporate WebDriver into a Gradle build, downloads the drivers outside of Gradle's dependency mechanism.

You might want to check out the code to see how they do it, or simply use the plugin.